# Keyboard dismisses on every character typed in text input in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Can I know why my keyboard automatically dismisses on every character typing on the text input field. I do a state change on character input, but why it dismisses the keyboard, I don't see any problem with the code.
I'm having this issue on android emulator, I haven't done on a real device or IOS/web, any help would be appreciated.

`Here is the code`

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  // components
  const FormInput = ({placeholder, ...rest}) => (
    <View style={{padding: 10, margin: 5, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000'}}>
      <TextInput
        {...rest}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        style={{width: 150, height: 30}}
      />
    </View>
  );

  const FormBtn = ({title}) => (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#e264e5',
        padding: 10,
        width: 170,
        height: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        margin: 5,
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  // states
  const [mail, setMail] = React.useState();
  const [pwd, setPwd] = React.useState();

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <FormInput
          placeholder="Email"
          onChangeText={txt => setMail(txt)}
          value={mail}
        />
        <FormInput
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={txt => setPwd(txt)}
          value={pwd}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <FormBtn title="Register" />
        <FormBtn title="Login" />
      </View>
      <Text>{mail}</Text>
      <Text>{pwd}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you suppose to bring your inline ui functions (`FormInput` and `FormBtn`) outside of your component and consider them as indipendent functional components. the following code represents my words:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

const FormInput = ({placeholder, ...rest}) => (
  <View style={{padding: 10, margin: 5, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000'}}>
    <TextInput
      {...rest}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      style={{width: 150, height: 30}}
    />
  </View>
);

const FormBtn = ({title}) => (
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#e264e5',
      padding: 10,
      width: 170,
      height: 50,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      margin: 5,
    }}>
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  // states
  const [mail, setMail] = React.useState();
  const [pwd, setPwd] = React.useState();

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <FormInput
          placeholder="Email"
          onChangeText={txt => setMail(txt)}
          value={mail}
        />
        <FormInput
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={txt => setPwd(txt)}
          value={pwd}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <FormBtn title="Register" />
        <FormBtn title="Login" />
      </View>
      <Text>{mail}</Text>
      <Text>{pwd}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};


export default App;
```

the reason that keyboard disappear every time you enter a new character is that by entering every character, states will update and your App component create new `FormInput` and `FormBtn` functions so that this action caused performance issues like this. you can see the number of functions added in your component by adding a Set:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

const functionsCounter = new Set();

const App = () => {
  // states
  const [mail, setMail] = React.useState();
  const [pwd, setPwd] = React.useState();

  const FormInput = ({placeholder, ...rest}) => (
    <View style={{padding: 10, margin: 5, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000'}}>
      <TextInput
        {...rest}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        style={{width: 150, height: 30}}
      />
    </View>
  );

  const FormBtn = ({title}) => (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#e264e5',
        padding: 10,
        width: 170,
        height: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        margin: 5,
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  functionsCounter.add(FormInput);
  functionsCounter.add(FormBtn);

  console.log('functionCounter', functionsCounter.size);
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <FormInput
          placeholder="Email"
          onChangeText={txt => setMail(txt)}
          value={mail}
        />
        <FormInput
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={txt => setPwd(txt)}
          value={pwd}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <FormBtn title="Register" />
        <FormBtn title="Login" />
      </View>
      <Text>{mail}</Text>
      <Text>{pwd}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```